# Spring Integration for Kafka - Configuring Multiple Topics

Tags: spring-integration, spring-kafka

There is a need for me to post certain messages to one topic and another set of messages to another topic, I am currently using Spring integration for Kafka to post messages to one topic, but I am looking for example about how can I post messages to different topics based on the situation.

I am using `int-kafka:producer-configuration` tags to create context

**Update**

Thank you that is working. I am using the below configuration in my application context xml 
                                                                            
                                                                                        and the below in my code to check get the desired TOPIC name                                                                                                             kafkaUpdate = channel.send(MessageBuilder.withPayload(jsonAuditLog).setHeader(KafkaHeaders.TOPIC, "").build(), kafkaTimeOut.longValue());

Code is working and I see messages getting posted to different topics as I wanted, but not sure if this is the rite way....

Comment: <int-kafka:outbound-channel-adapter kafka-producer-context ref="kafkaProducerContext" auto-startup="true" channel="inputToKafka"
topic-expression="headers['kafka_topic'] != null ? '${kafkaXmltopic}' : '${kafkatopic}'"/>

Answer (score 1):

What you are about is very old version. The latest Spring Integration Kafka `3.0.1` is based on the Spring Kafka `2.1.2` and there is no any `producer-configuration` for a long time already.

Consider to develop your application for the actual Apache Kafka `1.0.0`.

The new `<int-kafka:outbound-channel-adapter>` has `topic-expression` for your purpose:  https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/2.1.2.RELEASE/reference/html/_spring_integration.html#si-outbound

**UPDATE**

The old version has this attribute on the `<int-kafka:outbound-channel-adapter>`:

```
<xsd:attribute name="topic-expression" type="xsd:string">
                <xsd:annotation>
                    <xsd:documentation><![CDATA[
                                Specifies the expression to determine the name of the Kafka topic
                                against the Message at runtime.
                                This attribute is mutually exclusive with 'topic' attribute.
                            ]]></xsd:documentation>
                </xsd:annotation>
</xsd:attribute>
```

Comment: Thanks Bilan for the response, but there is a need for us to use the older version. If I have to update Spring Kafka and Spring Integration for Kafka, it will take sometime and more effort for testing. I tried to update it but looks to me that I need to update other Spring jars also and Spring-Integration-Kafka.xsd in application context. I was not able to find the xsd version which supports kafka-template

Comment: In the older version, is it possible to choose topic names dynamically?

Comment: See an UPDATE in my answer.

Comment: Used the below configuration in application context xml                                                    
                                                                                                             <int-kafka:outbound-channel-adapter kafka-producer-context ref="kafkaProducerContext" auto-startup="true" channel="inputToKafka"
topic-expression="headers['kafka_topic'] != null ? '${kafkaXmltopic}' : '${kafkatopic}'"/>

Comment: Does make sense for me. What is the point to check header and then use statically resolved value from the property placeholder?

Comment: This topic name is different in different environments i.e. DEV, QA & PROD. I need to make these topic names dynamic rather than hardcoding in code. So just checking if header property is null or not and if it is not null, then I will load the topic names from context.